# set role specific screen options in post summary page

Tags: posts, screen-options

I need to set different screen options(title,author,categories...) in post summary page for non admin users(editor,author..) which can not be altered by user him/her self.

Example :
[image]

This is the administrator view and I need to hide `View Count` & `SEO` columns for non admin users.

Does anybody have an idea, how to achieve this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume, you need something like editors can't see the category column or something like this.

This snippet might help you:

```
/** Remove "Options"-Panel, when User is not admin **/
add_filter( 'manage_posts_columns', 'change_columns_for_user', 10, 2 );
function change_columns_for_user( $columns, $post_type ){
    if( 'post' != $post_type )
        return $columns;

    if( current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) )
        return $columns;
    else{
        //Remove Categories
        unset( $columns['categories'] );
        //Remove Tags
        unset( $columns['tags'] );
        //Remove Comments
        unset( $columns['comments'] );
        return $columns;
    }

}
```

In this snippet we unset some columns if the user cant managa options. You know the options panel on the top: In this case, they wouldn't even show up in this panel no more.

> But It should not be able to change from the particular user login.

If you still want to disable the options panel for some users, have a look into this snippet:

```
/** Remove "Options"-Panel, when User is not admin **/
add_filter( 'screen_options_show_screen', 'remove_screen_settings', 10, 2 );
function remove_screen_settings( $show_screen, $class ){
    if( 'edit-post' != $class->id )
        return $show_screen;

    if( ! current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) )
        return false;
    else
        return true;
}
```

Comment: Worth mentioning that screen options are a per-user setting (in case people think a user can change a setting for everyone else!)

Comment: You don't need to use `else`. This usually is a sign of code smell. You aborted in all other cases so just return the value. Also about your second snippet: You can just `return ! ( current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) )` to return a `boolean` result and `!`/negate it :)

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [capabilities API](https://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities) to conditionally set screen options:

```
if ( current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) ) {
    // Administrator, add some options
} else {
    // Other roles, do something different
}
```

Comment: should I add this to `function.php` ?

Comment: Yes. But don't just chuck it in - this is an example of how to conditionally run code based on the current user role. You'll probably want to wrap it in a function and hook it to an appropriate action.

Answer (score 3):

I have accepted the @websupporter answer according to my question.

However I would like add few codes to specific question I have faced earlier.

I need to remove `Yoast SEO` plugin extra columns from the non admin users. In that specific case `Yoast SEO` provide the hook to disable the columns. So I used that as below.

```
/** Remove SEO columns when User is not admin**/
function remove_page_analysis_for_non_admin(){
    if( current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) )
        return true;
    else{
        return false;
    }
}
add_filter( 'wpseo_use_page_analysis', 'remove_page_analysis_for_non_admin', 10, 2 );
```

If anybody would interesting to remove it for all users, use following code

```
add_filter( 'wpseo_use_page_analysis', '__return_false' );
```

Answer (score 0):

You would use the `default_hidden_columns` filter. Here's an example of what I did to hide a column in the Media Library:

```
add_filter( 'default_hidden_columns', function( array $hidden, WP_Screen $screen ) {
    if ( isset( $screen->id ) && 'upload' === $screen->id ) {
        $hidden[] = 'imagify_optimized_file';
    }
    return $hidden;
}, 20, 2 );
```